# Unable to catch System.TypeLoadException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details> in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am initializing navigation page like this:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
```

Here's the `MainPage` XAML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage Title="Introduction" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LearningXamarin.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Next" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

`MainPage.xaml.cs` code:

```
async private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try { 
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new NextPage());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
          throw;
    }
}
```

Now when I click this button, it throws `Unable to catch System.TypeLoadException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>`. I tried adding `Try..Catch` block but it is not showing exception details.

`NextPage.xaml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage Title="Next" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LearningXamarin.NextPage">


</ContentPage>
```

`NextPage.xaml.cs` code:

```
public partial class NextPage : ContentPage
{
    public NextPage()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the code for NextPage

Comment: @Jason question updated.

Comment: If you want to claim that Xamarin cannot open the simple page on button click, that is a silly claim, sorry to say. So either there is something else or you have some problem in your dev environment, try to clean everything.

Comment: @IvanIčin Ok. I created a new project and it's working fine there. But what if something like this occurs in a complex project?

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva you debug and experiment till you find the problem, that's what the job of the developer is about.

Comment: @IvanIčin But I just want to know the ways to debug it. One way was to add try catch block but it didn't work. Is there any log maintained by Xamarin Framwork? I am also unable to view any exception in Output window.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva You can [Set breakpoints in source code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Overview) to check where problem is. By the way , you also can share sample project , I will check it.